# Currently playing song from Windows 10 'Now Playing' card

Tags: uwp, windows-10

Is it possible to query the metadata that is displayed when playing music on Windows 10?

[image: http://i63.tinypic.com/1q00mc.jpg]

While I found information about displaying the metadata from a `MediaPlayer` with SMTC and such, I can't find any way for a process (which doesn't play any media itself) to simply read out that same metadata.

Answer (score 9):

There's a .NET Framework wrapper that's able to accomplish this called [WindowsMediaController](https://github.com/DubyaDude/WindowsMediaController).

It does it by utilizing the [Windows.SDK.Contracts package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts) to use Windows Runtime APIs in .NET Framework.

Here's a basic implementation that will print the currently playing media:

```cs
using System;
using Windows.Media.Control;

//

public static void PrintCurrentlyPlaying()
{
   var sessionManager = GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   var currentSession = sessionManager.GetCurrentSession();
   var mediaProperties = currentSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
   Console.WriteLine($"Playing {mediaProperties.Title} by {mediaProperties.Artist}");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't possible, as there isn't an API that I know about that offers this.

Comment: GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager is added by MS after this answer.